# Where in Wordpress will i include my file so i can access its variables throughout the rest of the page?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, scope

I tried including my file in `header.php` or my theme's `index.php`, but I cannot access the variables in the included file from let's say my theme's `footer.php` or even my theme's page templates.

Here's what I'm including:

```
<?php

// some parameters
$var_research = 5;
$var_researchtrans = 7;
$var_output = 9;
$var_edit_indi = 11;
$var_contact = 15;
$var_transition = 19;

?>
```

Now what I need is to be able to use the variables in footer.php, for example.

Hope someone out there has an answer. Thanks, y'all.

**OK, here's how I made it work:**

*In functions.php*

```
<?php // functions.php

// ...

function my_var($va_var) {

    // some parameters
    $var_research = 5;
    $var_researchtrans = 7;
    $var_output = 9;
    $var_edit_indi = 11;
    $var_contact = 15;
    $var_transition = 19;
    $var_sometext = "text test";

    eval("\$return_var = $" . $va_var . ";");
    return $return_var;

}

?>
```

*and in footer.php*

```
<?php // footer.php

// ...

echo "blah blah " . my_var("var_sometext");

// ...

?>
```

It's working, but did I do it right? is there a better/right way to do this? Thanks again, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to include your own functions are in your theme's `functions.php` file.

If you want to access a variable in multiple files, you can create a function in your `functions.php` and access that function anywhere within the theme.

**In functions.php**

```
function your_variable()
{
    $var = 'your variable';
    return $var;
}
```

**And in your footer.php**

```
echo your_variable();
```

## For your updated query

```
function my_var($va_var) {

    $out = array();
    // some parameters
    $out['var_research'] = 5;
    $out['var_researchtrans'] = 7;
    $out['var_output'] = 9;
    $out['var_edit_indi'] = 11;
    $out['var_contact'] = 15;
    $out['var_transition'] = 19;
    $out['var_sometext'] = "text test";

    return $out[$va_var];

}
```

Comment: thanks @Indranil, i just included the code in my question. i'll try to work them into a function. any suggestions?

Comment: yet another update to show my answer, @Indranil. there a better way to do it?

Comment: A better way to store them would be to use an array. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your function does, but the place to define functions is in your themes functions.php file.

Comment: thanks @Jeremy, i just included the code in my question. how do you suggest i implement this in a function?

Comment: yet another update to show my answer, @Jeremy. there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

humm , the original solution for this problem is that you must save your vars as an option variable in wordpress , something like this :

```
<?php add_option( $name, $value, $deprecated, $autoload ); ?>
```

and the function :

```
<?php
function my_var($va_var) {
    add_option( 'var_research', '5', '', 'yes' );
}
?>
```

and in the footer.php you just need to use this for retrieve your variable:

```
<?php _e(get_option('admin_email')); ?>
```

Good Luck

Comment: please remember , do not use any home made solution , its better to first check the original one in the codex ;)